# Java - can't execute last if statement in a series of 1-7

Tags: java, if-statement

The 'selection' variable is used to call different methods and execute different blocks of code. Everything works fine except for when I want to exit the program (i.e. when selection == 7). Does anyone know why this is?

```
public class HW5Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean breakRequest = false;

    while(breakRequest == false){
    System.out.println("\nWelcome to JVHS, what would you like to do?");
    System.out.println("1. Admit a new dog (description unknown)");
    System.out.println("2. Admit a new dog (description known)");
    System.out.println("3. Display information about a particular dog");
    System.out.println("4. Adopt a dog");
    System.out.println("5. Euthanize a dog");
    System.out.println("6. Display information about the JVHS");
    System.out.println("7. Exit");
    int selection = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\nYour selection is "+ selection);

    HW5Dog dogObject = new HW5Dog();

    if(selection == 1)
        dogObject.addDog();

    if(selection == 2)
        dogObject.addDog2();

    if(selection == 3){
        dogObject.getAllDogs();
        //Ask which Dog you want and get its info
        System.out.println("Please enter the ID number of the dog you wish to display:");
        if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
            int dogID = scanner.nextInt();
            dogObject.getDog(dogID);    
        }
        else
            System.out.println("ERROR - INVALID INPUT: EXPECTING INTERGER, TRY AGAIN");
    }

    if(selection == 4){
        dogObject.getAllDogs();
        //Ask which Dog you want and get its info
        System.out.println("Please enter the ID number of the dog you wish to adopt:");
        if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
            int dogID = scanner.nextInt();
            dogObject.adopt(dogID);
        }
    }

    if(selection == 5){
        dogObject.getAllDogs();
        //Ask which Dog you want and get its info
        System.out.println("Please enter the ID number of the dog you wish to euthanize:");
        if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
            int dogID = scanner.nextInt();
            dogObject.euth(dogID);
    }

    if(selection == 6){
        dogObject.getJVHS();
    }

    if(selection == 7){
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
        scanner.close();
        breakRequest = true;
    }

    }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? _How_ doesn't it work? What do you expect it to do? What happens instead?

Comment: Look at the {} of selection 5 and below. Correct indentation is miracle...

Answer (score 4):

The issue is in the selection block above:

```
if(selection == 5){
    dogObject.getAllDogs();
    //Ask which Dog you want and get its info
    System.out.println("Please enter the ID number of the dog you wish to euthanize:");
    if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
        int dogID = scanner.nextInt();
        dogObject.euth(dogID);
}
```

You do not close the braces on the second `if` statement. It should instead be something like this:

```
if(selection == 5){
    dogObject.getAllDogs();
    //Ask which Dog you want and get its info
    System.out.println("Please enter the ID number of the dog you wish to euthanize:");
    if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int dogID = scanner.nextInt();
        dogObject.euth(dogID);
    }
}
```

*As mentioned in some of the comments, you should stick to a clear and consistent indentation style to make this problem easier to spot in the future.*

Comment: And this is why you always fix your indentation.

Comment: Not only fix identation, but also use brackets in control statements...I don't know which IDE You use, but I would recommend enabling some on file save actions like organizing Your imports and  formatting the file